# Не создаётся таблица в БД MySql после запуска Spring Boot приложения

Tags: java, mysql, spring, phpmyadmin, mvc

В проекте используется БД MySql, Open Server. Вот мой файл application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:8888/citatnik_bd
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

Вот моя сущность:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Quotes")
public class Quotes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long ID;

    private String ru, by, ua, en;

    public Long GetID() { return ID; }
    public void SetID(Long ID) { this.ID = ID; }

    public String GetBy() { return by; }
    public void SetBy(String by) { this.by = by; }

    public String GetRu() { return ru; }
    public void SetRu(String ru) { this.ru = ru; }

    public String GetUa() { return ua; }
    public void SetUa(String ua) { this.ua = ua; }

    public String GetEn() { return en; }
    public void SetEn(String en) { this.by = en; }
}
```

Кстати, в файле pom.xml всё хорошо, прописаны все необходимые зависисмости:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <version>8.0.30</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Привожу полный loggin out:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)

2023-07-31T19:01:34.457+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] c.Citatnik.Citatnik.CitatnikApplication  : Starting CitatnikApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 3336 (C:\Users\dddry\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Цитатник\Citatnik\target\classes started by dddry in C:\Users\dddry\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Цитатник\Citatnik)
2023-07-31T19:01:34.461+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] c.Citatnik.Citatnik.CitatnikApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-31T19:01:34.539+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-07-31T19:01:34.539+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-07-31T19:01:35.213+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-07-31T19:01:35.232+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 11 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-07-31T19:01:35.866+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-07-31T19:01:35.876+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-07-31T19:01:35.876+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
2023-07-31T19:01:35.945+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-07-31T19:01:35.946+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1405 ms
2023-07-31T19:01:36.094+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-07-31T19:01:36.148+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.6.Final
2023-07-31T19:01:36.149+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-07-31T19:01:36.272+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-07-31T19:01:36.396+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-07-31T19:01:36.409+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-07-31T19:01:36.664+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@41c02a96
2023-07-31T19:01:36.666+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-07-31T19:01:36.824+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-07-31T19:01:37.044+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-07-31T19:01:37.048+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-07-31T19:01:37.094+03:00  WARN 3336 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-07-31T19:01:37.542+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-07-31T19:01:37.574+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-07-31T19:01:37.585+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] c.Citatnik.Citatnik.CitatnikApplication  : Started CitatnikApplication in 3.679 seconds (process running for 4.084)
```

Я проверил порт, название БД, имя пользователя и пароль - всё правильно. Однако, когда я запускаю приложение и захожу в phpMyAdmin вижу сообщение, что таблиц в базе данных не обнаружено. В чём тут может быть дело?

P.S. Я уверен, что связь с БД создаётся - об этом свидетельствует строчка:

```
HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@41c02a96
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То, что в бд нет таблиц - это не ошибка.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, Spring Boot должен автоматически модерировать структуру базы данных согласно классам @Entity... Разве нет?

Comment: Ничего он не должен, Spring Boot - это надстройка над Spring, которая позволяет запускать приложения с командной строки.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но хотелось бы немного более понятного разъяснения ситуации. Почему у других работает именно так, зачем тогда вообще нужны классы @Entity?

Comment: Это всего лишь аннотация над классом, которая обрабатывается фреймворком, после чего создаётся таблица с названием класса. Если таблица не создаётся, то должна быть причина, а у тебя ее нету в вопросе. А хотение знать много не позволяет дать ответ здесь.

Comment: Вопрос звучит так: по какой причине Spring не создаёт в автоматическом режиме таблицу в базе данных, в соответствии с созданной аннотацией? Если для ответа необходима какая-либо дополнительно информация я с радостью её могу проставить.

Comment: Нет, так не пойдет. Причин может быть много, и какая может быть причина понять невозможно. Поэтому твой вопрос не имеет смысла. Уже не новичок, думаю знаешь как задавать вопросы здесь или дать ссылку?

Comment: Давайте ссылку...

Comment: Ссылка звучит так: [Как задавать вопрос на этом сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Не обсуждается, все вопросы отправлять на [Meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: "Я уверен, что связь с БД создаётся." - на чем основана эта уверенность? Что пишут в логах на запуске приложения?

Comment: `HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl` - эта строчка говорит о том, что связь создана. Я добавлю полный loggin output.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась путём замены

```
import javax.persistence.*;
```

на

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
```

(это связано с используемой версией Spring), а так же потребовалось удалить зависимость

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

поскольку мы используем

```
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
```

Помимо этого, во время первого запуска, видимо необходимо в файле конфигурации прописывать именно так:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

а при повторных запусках приложения заменить `create` на `update`.